# I am unable to use a class variable as a default argument for the same class's function

Tags: c++, this, default-arguments, this-pointer

I am well aware that line 7 is invalid . but I want to use the class variables as default argument to method(apple) .

```
class trial{

public:

int i=10 ;

    void apple(int i=this.i){
       cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    void display(){
         cout<<i<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Correct. Do you have a question?

Comment: Just pasting a bunch of code isn't very helpful. Please describe the problem you are facing, what error messages you get, what is the desired outcome? A lot of details are missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
void apple(int i=this.i){
     cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

… with

```
void apple(int i){
     cout<<i<<endl;
}

void apple(){
     apple(i);
}
```

You can't access member variables in the formal argument list of a function.

Comment: but thats what i want to do .

Comment: @YashBhardwaj Just insisting doesn't make it happen though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set default value like this.
If you want to display your object's variable insted function's argument with same name use:

```
void apple(int i){
     // class member
     cout << this.i << endl;
     // function variable
     cout << i << endl;
}
```